# File render issue in backbone

Tags: django, backbone.js, django-rest-framework

I am trying to make an application using backbone and Django Rest Framework and I am facing this issue with rendering the template. I get following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function`

**Backbone**

```
var EditBook = Backbone.View.extend({
el:'.page',
render: function (options) {
    var that = this;
    if(options.id) {
        var book = new Book({id: options.id});
        book.fetch()({
            success: function(book) {

                var template = _.template($('#edit-book-template').html(), {book: null});
                that.$el.html(template);
            }
        })
    } else {
        var template = _.template($('#edit-book-template').html(), {book: null});
        this.$el.html(template);
    }
}
});
```

I tried checking the control flow of the program and it looks like the error points at line: `success: function(book){` and there doesn't seem to be an error.  Kindly help since I am very new to backbone and searched every corner for help.

**Edit:** The issue was solved and hence have removed the irrelevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are invoking fetch result as a function.

Change the line:

```
book.fetch()({
    success: function(book) {
        var template = _.template($('#edit-book-template').html(), {book: null});
        that.$el.html(template);
    }
})
```

to:

```
book.fetch({
    success: function(book) {
        var template = _.template($('#edit-book-template').html(), {book: null});
        that.$el.html(template);
    }
});
```

Comment: My eyes must have missed it. Thanks alot.